# google-analytics.com blocking test cases on my local

Tags: testing, web-applications, selenium, web

I am running selenium test cases on local dev env... sometime a few of test case fail because they keep waiting for response ... looking at the status bar at the bottom in firefox.. it keeps saying

```
waiting for www.google-analytics.com....
```

since I am running everything on my local I do not understand where google-analytics.com come into play, can anyone advise me what is happening and how can I turn this off ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using windows AND "**you don't care about what www.google-analytics.com does in your site"** - you can add the following line in your **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file**

```
127.0.0.1 www.google-analytics.com
```

This will essentially redirect all the google-analytics.com calls to your local machine. Google analytics is usually used by analytic team to track the stats on site like which page is viewed mostly etc.

I feel that if you are doing automation, your requests should NOT be counted in as organic traffic. And hence should not go to google-analytics

Comment: Alternatively, you could ask the devs to implement a way to build the application with flags so analytics scripts are not loaded on dev environments.